# TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, cython, python-multiprocessing

trying to fix the data types of values in multiple dictionaries by multiprocessing but I keep getting this error:

TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object

```
def update_orders(self, created_after: str, marketplace=Marketplaces.US):
    orders = self._get_orders(created_after, marketplace)
    order_items = [self._get_order_items(order["AmazonOrderId"]) for order in orders]
    
    pool = mp.Pool(3)
    results = pool.map(self._fix_dtype, [orders, order_items])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    pprint(results)

def _fix_dtype(self, value: Any) -> Any:
    return fix_dtype_cython(value, {"ObjectID": id(self), "Childs": {"AmazonApiManagerID": id(self.api)}})

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def fix_dtype_cython(value, debug_information):
  cdef str lower_val
  cdef int n
  cdef list list_copy
  cdef dict dict_copy
  if isinstance(value, (int, float, bool, type(None), date, datetime)):
    return value
  
  elif isinstance(value, str):
    if value.isnumeric():
      if len(value) >= 10:
        return value
      return int(value)
    try:
      return float(value)
    except ValueError:
      lower_val = value.lower()
      if lower_val == "false":
        return False
      elif lower_val == "true":
        return True
      elif lower_val == "" or lower_val == "null" or lower_val == "none":
        return None
      else:
        return value
  
  elif isinstance(value, list):
    list_copy = value
    n = len(list_copy)
    if n == 0:
      return None
    return [fix_dtype_cython(list_copy[i], debug_information) for i in range(n)]
  
  elif isinstance(value, dict):
    dict_copy = value
    if len(dict_copy) == 0:
      return None
    return {key: fix_dtype_cython(val, debug_information) for key, val in dict_copy.items()}
    
  else:
    logging.critical(f"Failed to fix value '{value}' Therefore, returned None. {debug_information}")
    return None
```

I've tried not using cython, thought maybe thats the problem but didn't work and I have no idea where I'm doing wrong.

Edit:
Ok I find where is the problem.

```
def __init__(self, client: pymongo.MongoClient) -> None:
    self.client = client
    self.api = AmazonApiManager()
```

Here when I comment the self.client it works. But why though?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's still not possible to tell what you're actually doing from what you've written. But multiprocessing uses pickle a lot to pass things between processes. So you need to make sure all the arguments you're sending to pool are pickleable for example